# Session variable can not show in AJAX Function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session-variables

I am working in php where I am inserting some values to data base. And for that purpose i am using Ajax method.I am calling Ajax function on button click and inside ajax i am calling another php file where insertion occur and session variable update. But when insertion occur and i want to show the updates session variable in Ajax response, it shows old session variable and does not show the updated session vairable.

```
function showDiv() {
  document.getElementById('HelpDiv').style.display = "block";
  var value ="<?php  echo ''.$_SESSION['user_name']; ?>";
  alert(value);
  var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

  try {  
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // alert("ajax start");  
  } catch (e) {    
    alert("Your browser broke!");  
    // Internet Explorer Browsers

    try {
      ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      //alert("start2");  
    } catch (e) {
      try {
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        //  alert("start3");  
      } catch (e) {
        // Something went wrong
        alert("Your browser broke!");
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  var qst_id="<?php echo''.$question_id;?>";

  // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server and will update div section in the same page.
  ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    //var value ="<?php  echo ''.$_SESSION['user_name']; ?>";
    //alert(value);

    var t = ajaxRequest.readyState;
    if (t == 4) {
      document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = "<?php echo ''.$_SESSION['user_name']; ?>";

      // alert("ajax received");  
      var startSession = "<?php  session_start(); ?>";
      var value = "<?php  echo ''.$_SESSION['user_name']; ?>";
      alert(value);
    }
    // if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
    //   alet("ajax received");  
    // }
  }

  // passing value to the server script, ajax file
  var queryString = "?question_id=" + qst_id;   
  ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajax-login.php" + queryString, true);
  ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
```

```php
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['user_name'] = "asasd3";
  echo "".$_SESSION['user_name'];
?>
```

Comment: Seems you don't understand difference between client and server

Comment: You need to use the session value you `echo` back in the AJAX response, not the one that's available from PHP when your page loads. There are plenty of tutorials and questions available on AJAX and PHP if you search.

Comment: @u_mulder that may be, can you please help me , i want to update my php page with ajax, i want to send data to php through ajax and get updated value, can you tell me how i can do that. I am not php expert.thanks

Comment: The line `document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = "<?php  echo ''.$_SESSION['user_name']; ?>";` will processed once, so it will be "replaced" with something like: `document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = "1st_username";` and when the ajax request is done it always execute the line above. I hope it was clear, anyway you should consider to return a value from the ajax function to the response

Comment: so how i can show updated session vairable in ajax response, is there any aleternative method. i want to show updated values in ajax response

Comment: may forget forward slash in `ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajax-login.php" + queryString, true);` after "ajax-login.php/"

Answer (score 0):

First understand that $_SESSION variable are different than the HTML session variables : 
please read for more info on PHP session variable on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sessions.htm

I am using jQuery to ease solution

```
$.ajax({
  method : "POST",
  url: "someFileToUpdateTheSession.php",
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  success: function(data){
      // Do what you want to do when the session has been updated
      alert(data);
      console.log(data);
  }
});
```

PHP Side

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["user_name"] = 'anything you want';
    echo $_SESSION["user_name"];
    die();
?>
```